# 240 volt, 7 amp table saw - What type of outlet to install?

Tags: electrical

I bought a table saw at an auction, and the label indicates its 240 volt, 7amp saw.
The plug type has two horizontal prongs and a ground prong.
I was doing reading about the horizontal prongs being an older style plug.
I have a 30 amp breaker in the box and I've never added an outlet to it as of yet.
I'm based in the United States.

Should I buy a 240 volt, 15 amp outlet to install so I can run the saw or is there a more modern alternative?  I'm open to replacing the wire/plug on the table saw as it's pretty short length wise.

[image: Tablesaw]
[image: Plug]
[image: breaker box]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The saw plug looks like a NEMA 6-15, hot, hot, ground, so needs a NEMA 6-15 receptacle.

Change the 30 amp breaker to a dual 15 amp breaker and should be good to go.

Would not change the plug on the saw, since that is a safety factor to not plug it into another plug/circuit with the wrong amperage/voltage.  Extending/changing the wire might be a possibility to make it longer.

If adding a new circuit, might fall under newer electrical code that requires you to use a GFCI protected(breaker or receptacle) circuit.

Comment: The breaker box has two breakers together on one switch and it shows as 30.  Is that the same as a dual 15 amp? (I added a picture of the breaker box as well.)

Comment: Dual or double, sometimes even as a 240v breaker, could use two singles, but duals trip both legs together when two singles might only trip one leg if there is a problem.  RE-read your comment.  It is not the same, a 30 gives 30 amps on each leg, a 15 gives 15 amps on each leg.  You don't add up each leg to double the amperage.  If confused it is because of me not you.

Answer (score 6):

You need 240 volts, that is determined by the motor. This is not an "older style" plug, just less common; it is a standard 240V 15A plug. Receptacles for these are readily available.  What's probably not available to you is a 240V branch to a nearby outlet; you'd probably need to install that.  You can run a 15A or a 20A branch.  I would spend a little extra and use 12 AWG with a 20A dual breaker and a 20A receptacle, which will accept your 15A plug

The 30A breaker is not useful, you'd have to run #10 wire to your receptacle, and a 15/20A receptacle is not allowed to be fed from a 30A breaker.